# How do I make a box-shadow background fixed/static?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm using a box shadow for my background and I want it to be sticky/static when the user scrolls down the page.  Currently it loads to be 100% of the background but upon scrolling the background just turns to white the further down they scroll.

```css
/********************************************************************************/


/* HTML Body                                                                    */


/********************************************************************************/

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 20px #ED1A24;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype'
}
```

```html
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's best to not mess with your overall page layout for a styling thing. Here we can use a pseudo-element to apply the background.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 20px #ED1A24;
}

p {
  margin: 100px 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
<p>hi</p>
```

Comment: For the page I was working with, the background was centered. left: 0; was needed to bring the shadow into sync with edges of the page.